# SSH identity key ignored when using gitpython under supervisor

Tags: python, ssh, supervisord, gitpython

I have a simple Flask app that waits for webhooks from my repository host.  The webhook triggers a `git.pull()` of the latest revision from a predefined repository using `gitpython`.  The `gitpython` code is something like:

```
import git
repo_dir = '/path/to/repo'
g = git.cmd.Git(repo_dir)
g.pull()
```

The app is started with a supervisor script as a user, `admin`, whose ssh `id_rsa.pub` public key is registered with the repository as a deployment key.

When logged in as the registered user, `admin`, the app can be started from the command line and can successfully pull from the private repository.  When the app is started with `supervisor`, however, the `git.pull()` operation fails with a ssh auth error:

`Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

I can confirm the user launching the `supervisor` managed app is correct (`admin`).  This indicates that the supervisor script is not using the default SSH key for the same user.

I have seen some reference to setting one of several environment variables, `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` or a legacy `GIT_SSH`.  I have tried setting these values to both replacement ssh strings (ie `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i /path/to/key'`) and to executable files (ie `GIT_SSH='/path/to/myssh'`), but to no avail.

Has anyone encountered something like this?  It's an unexpected problem, that I am having trouble debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
import git
repo_dir = '/path/to/repo'
g = git.cmd.Git(repo_dir)
g.USE_SHELL = True
g.pull()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Git' object attribute 'USE_SHELL' is read-only

Comment: The `USE_SHELL` attribute must be set before instantiating. But still the same issue above, git pull fails.